# Laravel Livewire and Alpine.js entangled variable out of sync

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I'm facing a strange behavior with entangled variable. Here's the simplest example possible.

In my Livewire component:

```
public $myBoolValue = false;
```

In my blade view:

```
<div x-data="{toggle: @entangle('myBoolValue')}">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" @click="toggle = ! toggle"/>
    </label>
    <p>Livewire: {{ var_export($myBoolValue) }}</p>
    <p x-text="['Alpine.js: '+toggle]"></p>
</div>
```

Here's what happens:

[image]

After a page refresh, it seems that first click is working properly:

```
false -> check -> true -> OK
```

After that, `myBoolValue` gets out of sync once every 3 clicks:

```
true -> uncheck -> true -> WRONG
true -> check -> true -> OK? (dont know if it is in sync or just staying as it is)
true -> uncheck -> false -> OK
```

```
false -> check -> false -> WRONG
false -> uncheck -> false -> OK? (dont know if it is in sync or just staying as it is)
false -> check -> true -> OK
```

I dont get what i'm doing wrong.

---

**UPDATE:** Probably a [bug](https://github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/2064) in Livewire v2.3.2

---

**UPDATE 2:** Confirmed it was a bug in Livewire v2.3.2 and confirmed [fixed](https://github.com/livewire/livewire/pull/1968) in Livewire v2.3.4

Comment: Just tested and seems to work fine. It my be a network issue. If you look at the Network tab in devtools, how quick is the request that Livewire fires to update the `myBoolValue ` property?

Comment: On local environment it takes ~55ms. But I found this open issue https://github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/2064 which is probably affecting me too since i'm working on Livewire v2.3.2. Seems second and third requests are not beeing sent to server (no request shows in Network tab). Which Livewire version did you use to test this?

Comment: Ah interesting, yeah I'm on v2.3.1. Might be worth rolling that back until the issue is sorted.